# Formatear una lista

Tags: python, mongodb, discord.py, pymongo

quiero preguntar como podria formatear una string para que eliminara [ ' , al enviar el mensaje.

Estoy creando un bot para discord y guarde los nombres que obtuve en una lista pero cuando pido que me imprima no me sale formateado.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from models.mongo import db

@bot.command()
async def animelist(ctx, limit:int, page:int):
    my_list = []
    for anime in db.anime.find().skip(limit * (page - 1)).limit(limit):
        my_list.append(anime["titulo"])
    
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Anime List",
                              description = my_list,
                              color = discord.Color.blue())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el resultado que me da con el codigo anterior,pero me gustaria que quedara de la siguiente forma ¿Hay forma de que quede así?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa el `join` así:

```
anime = ["uno", "dos", "tres"]
juntos = "\n".join(anime)
print(juntos)
```

`join` toma un *iterable* (una lista, tupla, expresión generadora, etc.) compuesto de cadenas y las une en una sola interponiendo una inter-cadena ("\n" en este caso).

Ejemplo:

```
", ".join(["uno", "dos"])
```

produce

```
uno, dos
```

Fijate que la inter-cadena puede ser de cualquier largo, incluso cero.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma facil,, rapida, efectiva y con 1 linea de codigo seria utilizar la funcion `.join()` para unir una lista, en este caso le decimos que la una con un salto de linea `\n`

```py
    ...

    #unimos por salto de linea
    animes = "\n".join(my_list) 

    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Anime List",
                              description = animes,#enviamos la cadena
                              color = discord.Color.blue())
```

A tu lista le falta otros animes buenos °_°

Answer (score 0):

Despues de tener tu lista cargada, podrías hacer pasar todo a un string. Luego mandas como corresponda ese string. Sería asi:

```
anime_str = ''
for anime in anime_list:
    anime_str = anime_str + anime + '\n'
```